# Which Covariance Formula Is Best?

Tags: probability-distributions, covariance, regression-analysis

I've been looking around, but I am having some difficulty figuring out why I am seeing multiple formulas for solving for the covariance.

From three different sources, the covariance formulas have appeared to be the following:

[WolframMathworlds Definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Covariance.html): $$\text{Cov}(X,Y) =\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(x_i-\bar x)(y_i - \bar y)}{N} \tag{1} $$

"Regression Analysis by Example": $$\text{Cov}(Y,X) =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - \bar y)(x_i-\bar x)}{N-1} \tag{2}$$

"Probability And Statistics: For Engineers and Scientists"

*This formula appears to be used more for Discrete Joint Probability Distributions* $$\text{Cov}(X,Y) =\sum_x \sum_y (x-\mu_x)(y-\mu_y) f(x,y) \tag{3}$$

A common theme between the three formulas is that all three of them involve some division (this applies to Formula $(3)$ as well since $0 \le f(x,y) \le 1$)

However, it seems that all three formulas will end up with different values for $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$, which in turn should give different results should you solve for the correlation coefficient.

I'm aware that the $N-1$ has to do with bias / unbiasness, but I thought that if that were the case, WolframMathWorld would've made some sort of point about this.

What I am asking is, are these formulas (mainly formulas $1$ and $2$) close enough that they can be used interchangeably? Or should a certain formula be used for certain situations? Is one formula better than another? Also could the covariance represent the same thing in probability as well as regression analysis?

Comment: Your second formula deals with **sample covariance** which is a distinct concept (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance).

Comment: @Jean Marie So there are distinct concepts for covariance. Okay. And it involves division by $N-1$ similarly to how sample variance also involves division by $N-1$. Does that make formula $(1)$ population covariance?

Comment: I haven't used this term (population covariance) but it is possible it is used in some communities.

Comment: @WaveX Have you gotten answer for this question? I am confused if (3) and (1) are equivalent.

Comment: From my understanding use (1) if you happen to know the population means and you have a sample of size $N$. (3) is used more for joint probability distributions (which don't involve sample size) so it's the population covariance. See [covariance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance)